Subrouting using net/http in golang 1.22, issue with trailing "/" redirection
I am using the net/http standard library package for subrouting in Golang while developing a simple API. However, I encountered a problem. I have user routes for registration with POST /v1/users/. When I try to send a request to POST /v1/users, I get a 404 page not found error. I need to add a trailing / to make it work. I believe it should work with both trailing / and without trailing /. If you can help me fix this, it would be great.
Here is my main.go:
package main

import (
    "log/slog"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    routes "go-url-shortener-api/api/v1"
    "go-url-shortener-api/internal/config"
    "go-url-shortener-api/pkg/logger"
)

func main() {
    config, err := config.LoadConfig()
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("Error loading config", "error", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    router := routes.RegisterV1Routes()
    server := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":" + config.Port,
        Handler: router,
    }

    logger.Logger.Info("Starting server", slog.String("port", config.Port))
    server.ListenAndServe()
}

api/v1.go:
package routes

import "net/http"

func RegisterV1Routes() http.Handler {
    router := http.NewServeMux()

    router.Handle("/v1/", http.StripPrefix("/v1", RegisterRoutes()))

    return router
}

api/routes.go:
package routes

import "net/http"

func RegisterRoutes() http.Handler {
    router := http.NewServeMux()

    router.Handle("/users/", http.StripPrefix("/users", RegisterUserRoutes()))

    return router
}

api/user_routes.go:
package routes

import "net/http"

func RegisterUserRoutes() http.Handler {
    router := http.NewServeMux()

    router.HandleFunc("POST /", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("<p>POST /users</p>"))
    })
    router.HandleFunc("POST /login", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("<p>POST /users/login</p>"))
    })
    router.HandleFunc("POST /logout", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("<p>POST /users/logout</p>"))
    })

    return router
}

According to this documentation, it should redirect POST /v1/users to POST /v1/users/. Am I right or wrong?

The application trims the prefix /v1 from the request path before invoking the subrouter. The subrouter has no way to know that the actual request path has a /v1 prefix.
The subrouter sees the path /user and redirects to /users/ as  documented.  The browser reissues the request to /users/ and gets the 404 response.
An easy fix is to use a single router.
func Router() http.Handler {
    router := http.NewServeMux()
    RegisterV1Routes(router, "/v1")
    return router
}

func RegisterV1Routes(router *http.ServeMux, prefix string) {
    RegisterUserRoutes(router, prefix+"/users")
}

func RegisterUserRoutes(router *http.ServeMux, prefix string) {
    router.HandleFunc("POST "+prefix+"/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("<p>POST /users</p>"))
    })
    router.HandleFunc("POST "+prefix+"/login", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("<p>POST /users/login</p>"))
    })
    router.HandleFunc("POST "+prefix+"/logout", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("<p>POST /users/logout</p>"))
    })
}

...

server := http.Server{
    Addr:    ":" + config.Port,
    Handler: routes.Router(),
}


Thanks, I got it working, but now a new problem has come up. The redirect from POST /v1/users is being redirected to GET /v1/users/, causing me to receive a 405 Method Not Allowed error. This is due to the use of the redirect code StatusMovedPermanently 301 in Go, which causes the request to be redirected using the GET method. Instead, this should be StatusPermanentRedirect 308. More details can be found in this issue: github issue.

Avoid the redirect and 404s by ensuring that the client and server agree on the path.  Either modify the client to post to /v1/users/ or modify the server to register the handler at /v1/users.
